# Generating random number in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am using this function to generate random number between 1000 and 100.
but here according to me, in (max - min) + min, max- min  =900 and min= 100, so it should not generate numbers between 900 and 100? but it is returning numbers greater than 900 also how? I am confused. and do tell how to check the range for the numbers random function is generating? any help with this?

```
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100) + 100);
  console.log(x);
```

Comment: what is your expected answer?

Comment: between 1000 and 100, i am asking how its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function Math.random() returns a number between 0 and 1.

When use "Math.random() * (1000 - 100)", this part of the code generates a number between 0 and 1 then multiplies it by 900, which will give you a number between 0 and 900.

Now in the last block you do add 100 to the previously generated number which results in a number between 0 and 900 + 100, which gives a result between 100 and 1000.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for random numbers `Math.random() * (max - min) + min` is the correct one to get a uniformly distributed number between `min` and `max`.

`max - min` will give you the range in which you want to generate the random numbers. So in this case `1000 - 100` results in a range of `900`.

Multiplying by `Math.random()` will give you a random number in the range. So, with a `Math.random()` producing `0.5` after multiplying you get `450`.

Finally, adding `min` back to the random pick ensures the number you get is within bounds of `min` and `max`.

For example `Math.random()` produces `0.01` if we substitute in the formula we get `0.01 * (1000 - 100) = 9` which is *below* `min`. Conversely, if `Math.random()` produces `1` then `1 * (1000 - 100) = 900` which is the highest random number possible to get from the range and yet it's still below `max`. In both cases adding `min` to the result ensures the random number you get is within `max` and `min`

Answer (score 0):

**Multiply by (1000 -200) instead as you already have +100**

Because in case random number generated is anything greater than `800` you end exceeding range as you're adding `100` in it everytime

```js
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 200) + 100);
console.log(x);
```

**Thumb rule :-**

```
  Math.floor(Math.random() * - ( max - ( 2 * min ) ) + min )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function random(min, max) {
  console.log("Multiplying by: " + (max - min));
  console.log("And adding : " + min);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

console.log(random(100, 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Math.random()` generate floats, this need to be converted to an integer.

We can use `parseInt()`, but there is a shorthand, the `~~` [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). [Performances are known to be excellent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393373/performance-wise-how-fast-are-bitwise-operators-vs-normal-modulus).

```js
console.log(

 100 + ~~(Math.random() * 800)
  
)
```

One possible alternative is the [web crypto api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API), it might be a bit slower, but with the best randomness doable. This return an integer between 0 and 256.

```js
console.log(

  100 + ~~(crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] * 3.13)
      
)
```